# How to overlay text on image without alignment issue

Tags: html, css

Because of the position absolute and relative properties, I can't get it to show right on both desktop and mobile. The datebox text is always misaligned. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Here's my code.

```
<div class="container">
<% @events.each do |event| %>
<div class="event-picture-block">
  <span class="event-date-box">
    <%= event.date.strftime("%^b %e") %>
  </span>
  <%= link_to event_path(event), class:"link-margin" do %>
    <%= image_tag(event.image.url(:small), :class =>"event-image") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>

.event-picture-block { display: inline;}
.event-date-box { position: absolute; margin-top: 8em; margin-left: 2.4%; background-color: white; color: black; font-size: 35px; width: 10%; text-align: center; }
```

Mobile

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a fiddle. I guessed sizes so just take that into account.

https://jsfiddle.net/feov9x2h/1/

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="innerBox">
     <span class="date">NOV 20</span>
   </div>
   <div class="innerBox">
     <span class="date">NOV 20</span>
   </div>
   <div class="innerBox">
     <span class="date">NOV 20</span>
   </div>
   <div class="innerBox">
     <span class="date">NOV 20</span>
   </div>
   <div class="innerBox">
     <span class="date">NOV 20</span>
   </div>
   <div class="innerBox">
     <span class="date">NOV 20</span>
   </div>
</div>

.innerBox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.date{
  padding: 10px 5px;
  background:white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: Where would you put the image in there?

Comment: add it as a background: url(); so it will always be the size of the box

Comment: but the images are generated from a model, saved on aws s3.

Comment: so do they change at all or are they apart of the html to start? Are they apart of the  < a > tag?

Comment: they are part of the html. yeah it's also nested in the a tag.

Comment: i updated the fiddle above with an image, is that kinda how it looks?

Comment: Wow man, that's amazing. 1 last question, how would you center these 6 blocks? Add margin on the left of the container or ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135856/discussion-between-keith-and-brian-lau).

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
.event-picture-block { position: relative; }
.event-date-box { position: absolute; bottom: 10%; left: 10%; }
```

Comment: Nope it won't, `%` will always be messy on different resolutions. For a fixed position use `px` as it will remain at same position for all the conditions.

Comment: ^ He's right. 33.1% - The second row text goes outside the div. 33%, it's too small on mobile. 

But when I used px, it was screwed up. Unless I have to replace all % with px?

Comment: @OmprakashArumugam i'll try, but there's an another comment above that is similar. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should make the font size little down and make the width less.